# "Однако не многим удается уберечь даже самые сокровенные тайны и рано или поздно правда всплывает"

Tags: грамматика

"Однако не многим удается уберечь даже самые сокровенные тайны и рано или поздно правда всплывает".

Answer (score 1):

Безоговорочно правильный вариант (хотя бы в плане пунктуации):

***Однако не многим удается уберечь даже самые сокровенные тайны, и рано или поздно правда всплывает.***

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо просто поставить знаки препинания? Или что-то исправить в самом предложении? Если второе, то:

"Однако немногим удается уберечь (сохранить) даже самые сокровенные тайны, так что рано или поздно правда всегда всплывает".

Если принципиально именно с "и рано или поздно", то перед "и" запятая.

Comment: При чем тут принципиальность, если запятая нужна по грамматике составного предложения?

Comment: А вот хамить не надо. Здесь это не приветствуется.

Comment: Я не поддаюсь на троллинг, но модератору исправно сообщаю. ))) Ответ будет по сути?

Comment: Куда уж ближе к сути, членоголовый вы наш? )))